# use prolog to solve arithmetic expression

Tags: prolog, arithmetic-expressions

i am a novice in Prolog.Now I want to use Prolog to solve arithmetic expression problems. suppose we have a predicate like this: `expr(E,Val,Var,Sol)`
the first is the expression the second is the value the third one is the variable and the forth one is the result.
for example if we ask: `expr(3+x,2,x,S)`the answer will be `S=5`
and if we ask `expr(5*6,3,x,S)` the answer will be `S=30` in this case the x doesn't appear in the expression so we just ignore the variable and its value.
I want to know how can I implement it,can you guys give me some hints

Comment: I do not quite understand what you actually want to do... Solve equations? Or evaluate arithmetic expressions (with some additional substitution)?

Answer (score 2):

```
number_si(N) :-
   functor(N,_,_),
   number(N).

expr(V,Val,V,Val).
expr(N, _Val, _Var, N) :-
   number_si(N).
expr(A+B, Val,Var, R) :-
   expr(A, Val, Var, RA),
   expr(B, Val, Var, RB),
   R is RA+RB.
```

There are even cleaner ways to express this. Maybe someone else wants to contribute.

Comment: Fails for OPs query `expr(5*6,3,x,S)`

Comment: @gusbro: Can you help me on this?